# Sub-functions with reference parameter : how it works?

Tags: c++

I originally show the a program, which have a sub-function with non reference parameter like below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int inc(int x)
{
    x++;
    return x;
}
main()
{
    n=3;
    inc(n);
    cout<<n;
}
```

I think that about sub-function and may be it works like below:

when we call `inc(n)`, after that may be computer will create a var `int m;` and:

`m=n; m++;` and finally it is erased.

With sub-function with reference parameter :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int inc(int &x)
{
    x++;
    return x;
}
main()
{
    n=3;
    inc(n);
    cout<<n;
}
```

I think:

when we call `inc(n)`, after that may be computer will create a var `int &m=n`;
`m++; return m;` and finally it is erased, but `n` is changed by `n+1`.

Why am I asking? There are 2 reasons:
1) My fiend say that : there is not creation `int &m`, `function inc(int &x)` works such as : n run into and go out.
2) If there is `int &m` why everyone always say "`inc (int &x)` faster `inc(int x)`"?

Is my understanding of this correct? If not, can you tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the compiler point of view, a reference is not far from a pointer. So in

```
int inc(int &x)
{
    x++;
    return x;
}
...
inc(n);
```

you only pass a reference (the address of the variable `n`) to the function, and the callee variable is actually increased.

Whereas in

```
int inc(int x)
{
    x++;
    return x;
}
...
inc(n);
```

you pass by value and you are modifying a local copy.